# Multiple plots on the same figure using facet_wrap functionality of ggplot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, filter, facet-wrap

I am trying to add accumulated values of a particular years for multiple locations on top of the Figure that has statistics for those locations. Below is a sample code (taken from a solution propose to one of my previous question).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mydate <- as.data.frame(seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), to= as.Date("2019-12-31"), by="day"))
    colnames(mydate) <- "Date"
    Data <- data.frame(A = runif(7305,0,10), 
                       J = runif(7305,0,8), 
                       X = runif(7305,0,12), 
                       Z = runif(7305,0,10))

    DF <- data.frame(mydate, Data)

    Data_Statistics <- DF %>% mutate(Year = year(Date), Month = month(Date)) %>%
      pivot_longer(-c(Date,Year,Month), names_to = "variable", values_to = "values") %>% 
      filter(between(Month,5,10)) %>% 
      group_by(Year, variable) %>% 
      mutate(Cumulative = cumsum(values)) %>%
      mutate(NewDate = ymd(paste("2020", Month,day(Date), sep = "-"))) %>%
      ungroup() %>%
      group_by(variable, NewDate) %>%
      summarise(Median = median(Cumulative),
                Maximum = max(Cumulative),
                Minimum = min(Cumulative),
                Upper = quantile(Cumulative,0.75),
                Lower = quantile(Cumulative, 0.25))
```

I wanted to extract data for the year `2019` out of `Data_Statistics`, however, failed to do- I do not want statistics for the year 2019 but accumulated values along the period of my interest (May to October which corresponds to months 5 - 10)

```
 Data_2019 <- DF %>% mutate(Year = year(Date), Month = month(Date)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(Date,Year,Month), names_to = "variable", values_to = "values") %>% 
  filter(between(Month,5,10)) %>%
  filter(Year == 2019) %>% 
  group_by(Year, variable) %>% 
  mutate(Cumulative = cumsum(values))
```

Plotting the `Data_Statistics` using `facet_wrap` functionality of `ggplot` with the following sample code gave me attached Figure.

```
Data_Statistics %>% pivot_longer(cols = c(Median, Minimum,Maximum), names_to = "Statistic",values_to = "Value") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = NewDate))+
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = Lower, ymax = Upper, fill = "Upper / Lower"), alpha =0.5)+
  geom_line(aes(y = Value, color = Statistic, linetype = Statistic, size = Statistic))+
  facet_wrap(~variable, scales = "free")+
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b", date_breaks = "month", name = "Month")+
  ylab("Daily Cumulative Precipitation (mm)")+
  scale_size_manual(values = c(1.5,1,1.5))+
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("dashed","solid","dashed"))+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red","darkblue","black"))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = "cyan", name = "")
```

[image]

**My ultimate goal**

I want to add the year 2019 data on top of the figure for its respective `facets` (i.e., another geom_line) to see what we have in comparison to the statistics of all the previous years. 
Thank you.

Comment: new change in `ggplot2` v. 3.3.0, you can dodge your x-axis with this code so your labels do not overlap- `scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(n.dodge = 2))`

Comment: is your question how you can add 2019 to each panel and have them be another line? can you do the same summary you did for the data above for 2019 and then use `bind_rows()` to make one larger `data.frame` and then plot?

Comment: Hey Mike- nice suggestions. Here i am looking at before freeze up (May to October). Later, i want to use the data for winter period (Nov to March), so i would then have difficulty in extracting the year. For the winter period, my season would be november, december of the previous year and jan-March for the following year.

Comment: All, I updated my question. I do not want statistics for the year `2019`. I want to add accumulated value of the year `2019` to its respective `facets`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to overlay each facet with 2019 data, you add a new `geom_line` function to your ggplot. You need to first manipulate the 2019 data like you did for the total data ahead of this:

```r
Data_2019_plot <- Data_2019  %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(Median, Minimum,Maximum), names_to = "Statistic",values_to = "Value")
```

Now at the end of your ggplot sequence you add

```r
+ geom_line(data = Data_2019_plot, 
            aes(y = Value, color = Statistic, linetype = Statistic, size = Statistic))
```

and you get the following plot:
[image]

With your sample data, the 2019 lines overlap quite a lot so they don't look very clear. You may want to set a specific color for 2019 rather than setting it to the aesthetic mapping.

Comment: Hi Allan, Is there a way to not duplicate statistics for the year 2019. We already have year 2019 in `Data_Statistics`. Would be nice to just `extract` the year 2019 and add it as a separate `geom_line` for each `facet`.